# Differentiating between an economy condition and an economic condition

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning

1. "an economy condition" or "condition of economy"
2. "an economic condition"

Could anyone please through some vivid examples show me what is the subtle difference between the two?

Comment: Did you try to do an internet search for "economy condition"? How many examples did you find? Probably very few. We do not say 'economy condition.' This is because we use the adjective 'economic'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but the syntax (word structure) can reveal the meaning; usage of economy in a prepositional phrase *of the economy* is **subtly** different than the use as an adjective *economic*.

In saying

> a/the condition of the economy

the meaning of **condition** is closer to *status*:

> How is the economy doing? = What is the condition of the economy? = What is its status?

On the other hand, referring to

> an economic condition

*might* mean something that is **dependent** on the economy. Someone *might* say:

> In making a contract with another company, I emphasized the importance of our economic condition.

That might be a stretch, though. In general, I would say those two things can be taken to mean **the exact same thing**.